# While works till specific condition

Tags: java

I created a method in java to check whether the value is one of four letter.

```
public static String check(String m)
{
  while(!"A".equals(m)&&!"T".equals(m)&&!"C".equals(m)&&!"G".equals(m))
  { 
     JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Wrong try again");
  }
  return m;
}
```

but even if the value is not one of them the method return the wrong one
Is there any way to make while works till input equal on of four letter and just return them

Comment: Well you're not changing the value of `m` in your loop - so how do you expect it to get new input from the user?

Comment: In addition to Jon's comment, your while loop as it is now could just be an `if` statement

Answer (score 1):

You want to loop until you receive an input that meets your requirements, but the problem is that receiving an input doesn't just happen on its own. Once you call `check(someString)`, `m` becomes `someString`, and `m` does not ever change unless your check function assigns a new value to it. Thus, your while loop will check the same input every time, even if the user attempts to send new input. You must either call a function to receive new user input and put it into `m`, or replace your `while` loop with an `if` statement that returns `false` or `null`* and repeatedly ask for new input and call `check` on it until you get a result other than `false` or `null`.

*As your code is written, you would have to return `null`, however it is likely appropriate to change your method such that rather than returning the input, it returns `true` if the input is valid or returns `false` if the input is invalid, and then you can use this function as the condition in an `if` or `do-while` statement.

Example:

```
public static String getInput() {
    //m is probably not the best name, but you haven't told us what it means
    //replace "Enter m here" with whatever your input prompt is
    String m = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter m here"); 
    while(!check(m)) {
        //m is not valid, ask again
        //the "m =" is crucial
        m = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Wrong try again");
        //now returns to checking: if m checks true, program continues; otherwise, asks again
    }
    return m;
}
//you have a set of disallowed inputs, put it into a set rather than hardcode
private static final Set<String> disallowed = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
    "A", "T", "C", "G"
));
public static boolean check(String m) {
    return !disallowed.contains(m);
}
```

Comment: Nice,I was bit lazy,but you did the hard work,cheers.. :) +1,Add some code example,will be helpful to him

Answer (score 0):

Write your check method like this,

```
public static String check(String m)
{

  while(true)
  { 
    m =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter here");
     if(!"A".equals(m)&&!"T".equals(m)&&!"C".equals(m)&&!"G".equals(m))
     { 
     JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Wrong try again");
     }
     else
     {
       break;  //will terminate the loop
     }
  }
  return m;
}
```

You must understand the basics first,see the other answers too....

Comment: Use of `while(true)` and `break` is bad practice; instead you should put your `if` condition as the `while` condition.

Comment: I would like to know the reason for your statement,for this specific piece of code.. @Saposhiente

Comment: The reason is because a. you can and b. it's clearer and follows standard coding patterns; use of `while(true)` and `break` is effectively just `goto` which is discouraged in C and disallowed in Java for good reasons.

Comment: While this answer probably solves his problem, it does not help with his real question which is that he doesn't understand program  flow and the `while` loop.

Comment: @Saposhiente yeay right about that,but I was hesitating in saying to OP to go and read a book OR use google, ;)